# Trouble adding Jpanels correctly to a BoxLayout using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am attempting to create a GUI for a program I have previously written, but am having some trouble aligning some panels how I want them. Currently I have this code.

```
package javaapplication10;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GUITest extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 425;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    JPanel addPanel;
    JComboBox referenceList;
    JTextField callNoText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUITest gui = new GUITest( );
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GUITest( )
    {
        super("Library Search");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        addPanel = new JPanel( );
        addPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addPanel.setVisible(true);
        addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel info = new JPanel();
        info.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        info.setLayout(new BoxLayout(info, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel message_add = new JLabel("Adding a reference.");
        message_add.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
        message_add.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        JPanel typeSelect = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        typeSelect.add(new JLabel("Type: "));
        String[] references = {"Book", "Journal"};
        referenceList = new JComboBox(references);
        typeSelect.add(referenceList);
        typeSelect.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        JPanel callNoSelect = new JPanel();
        callNoText = new JTextField(20);
        callNoSelect.add(new JLabel("Call No:\t"));
        callNoSelect.add(callNoText);
        callNoSelect.setAlignmentX( Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );

        info.add(message_add);
        info.add(typeSelect);
        info.add(callNoSelect);

        addPanel.add(info, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(addPanel);

        JMenu commandMenu = new JMenu("Commands");
        JMenuItem addChoice = new JMenuItem("Add");
        commandMenu.add(addChoice);
        JMenuItem searchChoice = new JMenuItem("Search");
        commandMenu.add(searchChoice);
        JMenuItem quitChoice = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        commandMenu.add(quitChoice);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar( );
        bar.add(commandMenu);
        setJMenuBar(bar);
    }

}
```

This creates a GUI that looks like this: [image: Current GUI]

As you can see the two panels `typeSelect` and `callNoSelect` are added to the `addPanel`, but they look different than the label `message_add` that I added in before them. I've tested adding in another label, and it looks how I would like, but for some reason I can't get panels to do the same. 
I would like for the page to look something like this:

[image: Correct GUI]*

Also the reason I have this all in `addPanel` is that I will have other panels that I want to display to the user, which I will just turn visibility off and on for as needed. The reason I have addPanel as a BorderLayout is that I will eventually have some more controls in the eastern and southern quadrants once I work out how to get the center how I want it.

*I created the Correct GUI in paint in an attempt to better show what I want

Comment: `BoxLayout` is doing exactly what it was designed for, the problem is, it's not designed to do what you want. You might consider using something more flexible, like `GridBagLayout`, see [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some more details

Comment: Oh, by the way, you're title is little misleading to your actual ptoblem

Answer (score 1):

`JLabel` is transparent, where as `JPanel` is not.  So the `JLabel` is showing the background color of the `info` panel, which is white, while the `typeSelect` and `callNoText` are using their own default colors.  You could make these other panel's transparent, using `setOpaque(false)` or change their background color to match that of the `info` panel

As to your layout, you might consider using something more flexible, like `GridBagLayout`, see [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some more details